# How to control page get parameter in Yii CListView?

Tags: url, yii

Using Yii 1.1.12.  I have a [CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView) with ajax turned off:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'ajaxUpdate' => false,
)); ?>
```

The url for the link to the second page looks like:

`http://www.example.com/products?Product_page=2`

I want the url to look like:

`http://www.example.com/products?page=2`

How can I achieve this?

(A bonus would be to also describe how to get a url like `http://www.example.com/products/page/2`)

**Update**

As pointed out by elbek, I see the CListView has a `pager` property of type [CLinkPager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkPager). This in turn has a `pages` property of type [CPagination](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination) which has a property [pageVar](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#pageVar-detail) which is described as:

> name of the GET variable storing the current page index. Defaults to
>   'page'.

Sounds like it could be what I'm looking for, not sure how to modify this from the CListView though.

Answer (score 5):

Additionally to change the `pageVar` you have to modify the `$dataProvider`. You can do this when you are defining it in the controller action:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Products',array(
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageVar'=>'page'
    )
));
```

Alternatively you can of course modify the `$dataProvider` in the view itself before using it in the `CListView` : (not recommended-owing to separation of concerns)

```
$dataProvider->pagination=array('pageVar'=>'page');
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(/*rest of your code*/));
```

But with this change, to make your url look like `http://www.example.com/products/page/2` you'll need to slightly change the rule in `urlManager` from Suvera's answer:

```
'products/page/<page:\d+>'=>'products/index',
```

---

Note: If you don't need that type of url, you don't need the above rule, just specifying the `pageVar` does it.

Answer (score 3):

enable the urlManager component on your config.  And add the following rule at the top.

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    ......
    'rules'=>array(
        'products/page/<Product_page:\d+>'=>'products/index', //Add it in top
        ...........
        ...........
    ),
),
```

the above  rule will create a url  something like `http://www.example.com/products/page/2`

The value part in the rule `products/index`  is **products** controller and **index** action (this is important, so point it out to your actual route).

you can even create urls whatever way you want.

**ex 1:**

`'products/<Product_page:\d+>'=>'products/index'`

will give you   `http://www.example.com/products/2`

**ex 2**

`'TheAvengers/vs/Loki/<Product_page:\d+>'=>'products/index'`

will give you   `http://www.example.com/TheAvengers/vs/Loki/2`

Comment: Thanks it looks like this answers my bonus question perfectly.  Any thoughts on the first part of my question (i.e., turning http://someurl?Product_page=2 into http://someurl?page=2  Could you also solve with the urlManager?

Comment: Product_page: This is how Yii creates and understands query parameters ... `get_class($model).'_page'`.  You may need apache rewrite rule, and rule should rewrite page=2 to Product_page=2 so that Yii understands it.

Answer (score 0):

I think CListView has [pager](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php#L57) attribute(from its parent class)

You can try to set some attributes for this. I think it is CLinkPager instance.